# Passenger+Apache2+RubyonRails installation fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache2, passenger, ubuntu-11.04

Now I'm trying to install Passenger for RoR on Ubuntu 11.04. I already have apache2 and RoR, also I installed passenger gems. But when I continue with this command:
sudo passenger-install-apache2-module
it says that he can't find this command.
By the way, command 'passenger' he also don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you installed the passenger gem the `passenger-install-apache2-module` file could be in a few different places.

If you are using the default 1.8.7 ruby installation on Ubuntu it should be in here...

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/
```

In there you should find a passenger folder with the version you installed, example...

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5
```

Within that folder there should be a `bin/` directory, and within there is `passenger-install-apache2-module`

Failing that, make sure you installed the gem with sudo and try again.

Comment: thanks, i installed passenger and found folder, but the another problem..console(command line) doesn't do command 'passenger start', for example..it says: 'passenger' unknown command